# Is the kernel updated from centos yum appropriate for redhat distribution？

Tags: linux, centos

I didnt buy the RedHat subscription service since my RedHat was in a  test  environment. One  day  the system kernel needs to be updated. Then I somehow replaced the RedHat yum application with Centos yum and got the kernel updated. I was wondering if this kernel differs from the the one updated with RedHat yum from RedHat repo.  What components could have been modified or added within the kernel space. Thanks.

Comment: Using CentOS packages on RHEL will make it harder to get support from Redhat.  That said, the CentOS kernel will be built exactly the same, using the same source code as would be found on RHEL.  There is just a slightly longer delay to get kernel updates.  I would rebuild that system at some point however.  Mixing the distros may cause you grief at some point.

Comment: Thanks, but would you mind being more specific about the "grief" .What kind of difficulties I would probably encounter as using the centos kernel on RedHat.

Comment: If you pull a listing of base/updates from each of the RHEL/CentOS repos, you can verify for yourself if there will be a problem.  You will need to sort packages by version.  Ensure that on the system you test this on, that you also add the same 3rd party repos that you use, such as EPEL, and do the same test.  In some cases, the dependency files of some 3rd party packages may cause problems when mixing CentOS and RHEL.  This could easily become a full topic of discussion if we get into the weeds.

Comment: @Aaron Understood, thanks for figuring this out. 